# Taking self as an argument in a block does not cause a circular reference, but an external reference to self does

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

Who can tell me why the following code causes different results when the test parameter and the testMember variable point to the same address

```
@interface TestClass : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, copy) void (^testBlock)(TestClass *test);

@end

@implementation TestClass

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.testBlock(self);
}

@end

@implementation OtherClass

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    TestClass *testMember = [[TestClass alloc] init];

    // Case 1
    testMember.testBlock = ^(TestClass *test) {
        NSLog(@"%@",test); // This does not create circular references
    };

    // Case 2
    testMember.testBlock = ^(TestClass *test) {
        NSLog(@"%@",testMember); // This creates circular references
    };
}

@end
```

Comment: Case 1 captures argument only when method got executed and release it after completion
Case 2 captures referenced object for all block's life cycle

Answer (score 0):

For the case 1,  the `test` variable is just a local function parameter, the block didn't retain any other variables from outside.

For the case 2, the `testMember` object comes from block outside when defining the block, the block retains its reference count. Since the `testBlock` is defined as a property of class `TestClass`, so the `testMember` owns the `testBlock`. So, the `testMember` and `testBlock` retain each other, that's the *circular references*.

To fix the circular retain issue of case 2, use this:

```
__weak TestObject *weakMember = testMember;

testMember.testBlock = ^(TestClass *test) {
    __strong TestObject *strongMember = weakMember;
    NSLog(@"%@", strongMember);
};
```

Because the `weakMember` variable won't increase the reference count of real `testMember` object, so did the `testBlock`. When starting executing the `testBlock`, the `strongMember` try to retain the `weakMember` object (which may get nil value depends on your logic design) and get decreased of reference count when finishing the block.